# what classifier does in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

Query:

```
Select x classifier from tabx x
```

returns rows with one column named 'classifier' with list of values from the row.

Does anybody know where such features are documented? Is it the only usage of the keyword? I tried to google it but I've found only list of postgresql reserved keywords without explanation.
Example

[image]

It works like String_agg with ',' delimiter, but for a row.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a column *alias*.

For columns it's documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS) and for tables it's documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)

The name of the alias is irrelevant and bears no special meaning (including the word "classifier"). It just has to be a valid [SQL identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Using an alias won't change anything in the resulting data.

If you use the (optional) `AS` keyword, it might be a bit more obvious:

```
select some_column as something_else
from some_table as another_name;
```

The reference `x` refers to the table alias specified in the `FROM` clause and refers to the complete row/record. It's not the column alias ("classifier") that does this, it's the reference to the table.

This behaviour is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) in the manual

---

**Edit** after a new query was shown.

```
select a classifier, a.classifier
from t_attribute a;
```

The part `a classifier` still gives an alias to the record column (as explained above). `a.classifier`  simply accesses a column from the table `t_attribute`.

It could also have been written as:

```
select a as the_complete_row, a.classifier as classifier
from t_attribute a;
```

Comment: This is not an answer for my question. I ask for a keword 'classifier' which makes a list from values of the row.

Comment: @KalinaMielke: that's just a name the author of the query chose. She/He could have named it `whatever` or `i_want_to_confuse_people`. And as I have explained: "***It's not the column alias ("classifier") that does this, it's the reference to the table***"

Comment: look at the image pls.

Comment: @KalinaMielke: that doesn't really change my answer `a classifier` is still giving the record an alias. And `a.classifier` simply access a column named `classifier` in the table `t_attribute`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Alias for the record. I got it. I've found  classifier as keyword https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html, so  - my mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KalinaMielke  That docs says it is a reserved word in SQL:2016 standard.  Whatever it does in the standard does not seem to be implemented in PostgreSQL.